# Office 365 groups vs Yammer vs Teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, yammer, office-365-groups, microsoft-teams

What are the use cases or scenarios where you would choose one of these 3 : **Yammer, Office groups , MS Teams**. I know its kind of early stage of adoption , but is there anyone who has implemented this effectively in their intranet and would like to share some key things regarding this.

Answer (score 5):

The question is really a Yammer group vs an Office group.

And for all intents and purposes, an Office group is superior to a Yammer group. You have more functionality (Yammer or outlook for conversations, file storage, Planner, Power BI, Teams, OneNote) versus what Yammer offers.

Comment: But with Yammer integration with office 365 groups , i feel there is more overlap between functionalities and differentiating elements becomes very narrow.  For example one key difference i found so far is that yammer group gives me option to search in conversations while outlook groups does not

Answer (score 4):

For our company, the factors that we took into account to choose between Yammer and Teams, are as follow,

- Sharing Files. We have a hard time in sharing files in Yammer but Teams is integrated with SharePoint Libraries.
- Cost: Yammer is free for external users. For Teams, you need to pay for each member as of now.
- Planner: In Teams you could use Planner for tasks management. It's like Trello and is friendly.
- Rich Text Formatting is supported on Temas. You can bold or color your text. It's a good method to empahsize important stuff.
- Tagging are more friendly on Yammer.

And more factors that I explained in detail in my [Yammer vs Microsoft Teams Blog](https://bsuperiorsystem.com/blog/yammer-vs-microsoft-teams/). Eventually, we ended up choosing Teams.